# Xamarin Forms - WCF completed event not changing components

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, label, xamarin.forms

Currently i'm working on a Xamarin.Forms application with WCF. The app makes a connection to the WCF host and I get a response back, only I can't do anything with the results of the response.

My code of the method that's supposed to take care of the response is:

```
private static void ClientOnGetHelloDataCompleted(object sender, GetHelloDataCompletedEventsArgs getHelloDataCompletedEventArgs)
{
string msg = null;

if(getHelloDataCompletedEventArgs.Error != null)
   {
      msg = getHelloDataCompletedEventArgs.Error.Message;
   }
   else if(getHelloDataCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled != null)
   {
      msg = "Request was cancelled";
   }
   else
   {
      lblText.Text = getHelloDataCompletedEventArgs.Results.Name;
   }
}
```

When I debug I can see Results.Name is filled, but for some reason it doesn't update the label named lblText.

This method is placed in de App.cs (Xamarin Forms portable project).

Anyone here that can help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you updating lblText on the UI thread?

Comment: How do I know i'm on the UI thread? I tried alot of stuff like InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
    // manipulate UI controls
});
but nothing seems to update the label.

Comment: Did you try Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread?

Comment: After getting a bluescreen it suddenly does work. I think maybe there was a problem with the Mac creating a new version of the application. I found out whith debugging it stopped at breakpoints that weren't even possible to hit in that version. Seems to work with Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread :)

Answer (score 0):

you should refresh the U.I in the main thread, here is the fix

```
  else
  {  
         InvokeOnMainThread(() =>   lblText.Text =   getHelloDataCompletedEventArgs.Results.Name);

   }
```